# grails def vs Object vs Void

Tags: groovy

what is the difference between these 3?

```
def search(String id) {
 //code
}

Object search(String id) {
 //code
}

void search(String id) {
 //code
}
```

specially between `def` and `Object`.

Comment: you should not write `Void` here but `void`.  Returning from there will give you casting errors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`def` is an alias for `Object`, so the first 2 signatures are identical.

the difference between the 1st two and the 3rd is, that you can return null or an instance of any class from the 1 and 2, whereas you can return only null from the 3rd one.